# How to ignore parent div padding

Tags: html, css

I have an image (inner-img) inside a div with padding (inner-div) and I need to make this image to fit the outside div (main-div). I tried to use negative margin but is not working. Any light?

```css
.main-div {
  width: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}

.inner-img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.inner-div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
    <img class="inner-img" src="https://plainbackground.com/plain1024/60b13b.png" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia veniam fugiat et accusamus iusto quos beatae eum, corrupti odit animi porro adipisci quasi eligendi error non cumque ex ut quod.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change your markup, you can use negative margin on `.inner-img` so that the image breaks out of `.inner-div`

```css
.main-div {
  width: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}

.inner-img {
  max-width: calc(100% + 40px);
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.inner-div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
    <img class="inner-img" src="https://plainbackground.com/plain1024/60b13b.png" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia veniam fugiat et accusamus iusto quos beatae eum, corrupti odit animi porro adipisci quasi eligendi error non cumque ex ut quod.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Moved the `img` out of the inner div and placed it in the outer div. Doing this allows the `img` to expand to the constraints of it's parent which is now `.main-div`:

This may not work for your use case but thought it worth mentioning.

```css
.main-div {
  width: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}

.inner-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.inner-div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <img class="inner-img" src="https://plainbackground.com/plain1024/60b13b.png" alt="">
  <div class="inner-div">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia veniam fugiat et accusamus iusto quos beatae eum, corrupti odit animi porro adipisci quasi eligendi error non cumque ex ut quod.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Rob, have you only changed the max-width to width? when I run into my code, it still stuck in inner-div. How is it working on this snippet and not on my code?

Comment: Look at the Html. I moved the `img` to the outer (.main-div) div.

Comment: Yes I see now. But I can't do that in my case. The "inner-div" is a group of information, so the image should remain inside it. Any other solution to that?